# Proof of finite additivity

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

Hello, could someone please clarify why exactly(from first line of the proof) it follows that events An are disjoint? Also, why is the union of P(Ai), until n, equal to union of P(Ai), until infinity? I understood the proof but don't quite understand from where these 2 things were derived.

Comment: The standard [Axioms of Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) include countable additivity (from which the given proposition follows trivially).  Not sure what axioms you are starting from.

Comment: To your specific question:  if $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are all disjoint, then adding countably many copies of the empty set clearly retains that property.

Comment: @lulu but from what I understand, they say An are disjoint because Am are all empty. How do they conclude from the first statement that An are disjoint. Or am I not understanding this properly?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Say we start with $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ which are assumed to be disjoint and then we define $A_i=\emptyset$ for $i>n$.  Now consider $A_r\cap A_s$ for some $r\neq s$.  We have two cases.  Either both $r,s≤n$ or not.  If both are $≤n$ then this intersection is empty by assumption.  If at least one is $≥n$ then the intersection is obviously empty (since at least one of the two terms is empty).  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu ohh, so it was assumed, not concluded( the An disjoint part). Okay I get it. Yes, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, the proposition clearly requires $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ to be disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question that you ask is nicely answered  by @lulu.

Let me answer the second question: the author basically defines
  the sets $A_{n+1}=\emptyset$, $A_{n+2}=\emptyset$, $A_{n+3}=\emptyset$, ... and so on. Thus it follows that 
  \begin{equation}\tag{1}
   \bigcup \limits_{i=n+1}^\infty A_i=\emptyset.
  \end{equation}

Then we have 
  \begin{align*}
  \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i&=\big(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i\big) \bigcup \emptyset\\
  &\stackrel{(1)}{=}\big(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i\big) \bigcup \big(\bigcup \limits_{i=n+1}^\infty A_i\big)\\
  &=\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i
    \end{align*}
  It follows that $\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i=\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ , hence

$$P(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i)=P(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i).$$